# std::fmod abysmal double precision

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, fmod

`fmod(1001.0, 0.0001)` is giving `0.00009999999995`, which seems like a very low precision (10<sup>-5</sup>), given the expected result of `0`.

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod), `fmod()` is implementable using `remainder()`, but `remainder(1001.0, 0.0001)` gives `-4.796965775988316e-14` (still far from `double` precision, but much better than 10<sup>-5</sup>).

Why does `fmod` precision depend on input arguments that much? Is it normal?

MCVE:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a = 1001.0, b = 0.0001;
    cout << setprecision(16);
    cout << "fmod:      " << fmod(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "remainder: " << remainder(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "actual:    " << a-floor(a/b)*b << endl;
    cout << "a/b:       " << a / b << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
fmod:      9.999999995203035e-05
remainder: -4.796965775988316e-14
actual:    0
a/b:       10010000
```

(same result with GCC, Clang, MSVC, with and without optimization)

[Live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/58MjKf)

Comment: The problem is that `0.0001` can't be represented precisely in binary floating point.

Comment: I've reopened, but I think if you simply print `b` with many digits of precision you'll be enlightened.

Comment: @Barmar I'm going to ruin the surprise: `0.0001` is actually `0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125` to the computer, assuming the almost ubiquitous [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representation.  Meantime `1001.0` is exact.

Comment: Another approach is to post all FP values using `%a` for their exactness without dozens of digits.

Comment: Apparently the moral of the story is to not assume you know floating point :P

Comment: @chux or use the [`std::hexfloat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hexfloat/) modifier, if you want to keep using `std::cout` (requires C++11).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If we modify your program to:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a = 1001.0, b = 0.0001;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(32) << std::left;
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "a:" << a << "\n"; 
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "b:" << b << "\n"; 
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "fmod:" << fmod(a, b) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "remainder:" << remainder(a, b) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "floor a/b:" << floor(a/b) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "actual:" << a-floor(a/b)*b << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "a/b:" << a / b << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << "floor 10009999:" << floor(10009999.99999999952) << "\n";
}
```

It outputs:

```
a:              1001
b:              0.00010000000000000000479217360238593
fmod:           9.9999999952030347032290447106817e-05
remainder:      -4.796965775988315527911254321225e-14
floor a/b:      10010000
actual:         0
a/b:            10010000
floor 10009999: 10010000
```

we can see that `0.0001` is not representable as a `double` so `b` is actually set to `0.00010000000000000000479217360238593`.

This results in `a/b` being `10009999.9999999995203034224` which therefore means `fmod` should return `1001 - 10009999*0.00010000000000000000479217360238593` which is `9.99999999520303470323e-5`.

(numbers calculated in speedcrunch so may not match exactly IEEE double values)

The reason your "actual" value is different is that `floor(a/b)` returns `10010000` not the exact value used by `fmod` which is `10009999`, this is itself due to `10009999.99999999952` not being representable as a double so it is rounded to `10010000` before being passed to floor.

Answer (score 23):

`fmod` produces exact results, with no error.

Given the C++ source code `fmod(1001.0, 0.0001)` in an implementation using IEEE-754 binary64 (the most commonly used format for `double`), the source text `0.0001` is converted to the `double` value 0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125.

Then 1001 = 10009999• 0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125 + 0.000099999999952030347032290447106817055100691504776477813720703125, so `fmod(1001, 0.0001)` is exactly 0.000099999999952030347032290447106817055100691504776477813720703125.

The only error occurs in converting the decimal numeral in the source text to the binary-based `double` format. There is no error in the `fmod` operation.

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental issue here (the IEEE-754 representation of `0.0001`) has been well-established already, but just for kicks, I copied the implementation of `fmod` using `std::remainder` from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod and compared it with `std::fmod`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

// Possible implementation of std::fmod according to cppreference.com
double fmod2(double x, double y)
{
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
    double result = std::remainder(std::fabs(x), (y = std::fabs(y)));
    if (std::signbit(result)) result += y;
    return std::copysign(result, x);
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    double b = 0.0001;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(25);
    std::cout << "              b:" << std::setw(35) << b << "\n"; 
    
    double m = 10010000.0;
    double c = m * b;
    double d = 1001.0 - m * b;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(32);
    std::cout << "     10010000*b:" << std::setw(6) << c << "\n"; 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(25);
    std::cout << "1001-10010000*b:" << std::setw(6) << d << "\n";
    
    long double m2 = 10010000.0;
    long double c2 = m2 * b;
    long double d2 = 1001.0 - m2 * b;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(32);
    std::cout << "     10010000*b:" << std::setw(35) << c2 << "\n"; 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(25);
    std::cout << "1001-10010000*b:" << std::setw(35) << d2 << "\n";
    
    std::cout << "      remainder:" << std::setw(35) << std::remainder(1001.0, b) << "\n"; 
    std::cout << "           fmod:" << std::setw(35) << std::fmod(1001.0, b) << "\n"; 
    std::cout << "          fmod2:" << std::setw(35) << fmod2(1001.0, b) << "\n"; 
    std::cout << " fmod-remainder:" << std::setw(35) <<
                 std::fmod(1001.0, b) - std::remainder(1001.0, b) << "\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
              b:     0.0001000000000000000047921736
     10010000*b:  1001
1001-10010000*b:     0
     10010000*b:  1001.0000000000000479616346638068
1001-10010000*b:    -4.796163466380676254630089e-14
      remainder:    -4.796965775988315527911254e-14
           fmod:     9.999999995203034703229045e-05
          fmod2:     9.999999995203034703229045e-05
 fmod-remainder:     0.0001000000000000000047921736
```

As illustrated by the last two lines of output, the actual `std::fmod` (at least in this implementation) matches the implementation suggested on the cppreference page, at least for this example.

We also see that 64 bits of IEEE-754 is not enough precision to show that
`10010000 * 0.0001` differs from an integer.
But if we go to 128 bits, the fractional part is clearly represented,
and when we subtract this from `1001.0` we find that the remainder is approximately the same as the return value of `std::remainder`.
(The difference is presumably due to `std::remainder` being computed with fewer than 128 bits; it may be using 80-bit arithmetic.)

Finally, note that `std::fmod(1001.0, b) - std::remainder(1001.0, b)`
turns out to be equal to the 64-bit IEEE-754 value of `0.0001`.
That is, both functions are returning results that are congruent to the same value modulo `0.0001000000000000000047921736`,
but `std::fmod` chooses the smallest positive value, while
`std::remainder` chooses the value closest to zero.